# How to remove dots from a pasted string

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I wrote some JavaScript code that should remove dots from pasted strings of numbers when inserting them into a table. However, when I try to paste a value into the table, I immediately get an alert and the function doesn't remove the dots.

For example, when pasting the number 11.11, I want to receive the value 1111.

Here's the code I'm using:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#MY_IG_ig > div.a-IG-body').on('paste', function (e) {

    var clipboardData, pastedData;
    clipboardData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
  
    pastedData = pastedData.split('.').join('');
  
    if (!/^\d+$/.test(pastedData)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('Must be a number!');
    }
  });
});
```

Edit:

I fixed my code as follows:

```js
if (!/^\d+$/.test(pastedData)) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Enter a valid number!');
} else {
  $(e.target).val(pastedData);
}
```

On the console, the values are correct, 11.11 is changed to 1111, but when I paste the value into the table, I get 111111.11. What could be causing this?

Comment: Can you provide some example input and expected results?

Comment: pastedDate = pastedData.replace(".", "")  Have you output the string to see what you're actually getting? Might even be a \n at the end of the string?

Comment: Can you share more test input and expected output also?
It will help in understanding more about the question .

Comment: This code works in the browser, it must be [tag:oracle-apex] specific

Answer (score 1):

Move `e.preventDefault();` out of the if statement, so that it is executed every time.

Currently your function adds 1111 and the default behaviour adds the original value of 11.11